# How to embed google map dynamically as template in another template

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, templates

The google map displays normally as static html.
But we need to show datas dynamically on google map so we need to embed it as a template to another template using javascript.
It appears to be blank. The source code of webpages shows that the 'initialize()' function has been called but the map doesn't appear

here is index.html

```
<body>
<div class = "heatmap">
    {% include 'origin.html' %}
</div>
</body>
```

here is origin.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>
<script>
// Adding 500 Data Points
var map, pointarray, heatmap;

var taxiData = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586)
 ];

function initialize() {
      alert('map appears!')
      var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.774546, -122.433523),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
 };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);

heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
data: pointArray});

 heatmap.setMap(map);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>

<div id="map-canvas">this is the map</div>
```

here is css file:

```
html{
height: 90%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
height: 90%; 
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px;
font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

#map-canvas {
height: 90%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

We are using jinja2 template in Google App Engine application if this matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.heatmap` needs a height, otherwise the 90%-height of `#map-canvas` will be calculated as 0px

Comment: It works after adding the attribute in css file. Having been stuck by this problem for a long time. Thank you very much!